# append nested lists

Tags: prolog

I want to append two lists say [1,2] and [3,4] to a single list as ,

`[[1,2],[3,4]]`. How could this be achieved in prolog. I always get it as `[1,2,3,4]`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
glue(A, B, [A, B]).
```

There's not much to say about this one!

Usage is

```
?- glue([1, 2], [3, 4], R).
R = [[1, 2], [3, 4]].
```

But really, you can hardcode it instead of wrapping it in a predicate.